# Cannot open a PDF on iPad from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ios, pdf, safari

I am downloading a PDF (and others types but lets focus on PDF) through an IIS ASP.NET web application.  The download works on every other platform except Safari on iPad and iPhone 4S.  I know that iOS does not support document downloads, but Safari does not open the PDF either.  Clicking the link has no response on the devices. I have tried a couple of solutions listed below (take out/replace headers mostly):

http://nilangshah.wordpress.com/2007/05/28/successfully-stream-a-pdf-to-browser-through-https/ and 
[PHP: Download file script not working on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849197/php-download-file-script-not-working-on-ipad)

I can see no errors on the device other than a "expected MIME" type but I also see that in the desktop browser versions and it doesn't stop the download.  I am running through a proxy and can see the device receives a 200 response with the proper headers.  I have successfully opened a PDF from other sites with the device.

I am just getting started reacquainted with ASP and iOS so any debug insights would also be appreciated.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
context.Response.Buffer = false;
context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.ClearHeaders();
context.Response.ClearContent();

context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

string fileName = "thefile.pdf";

System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = context.Request.Browser;
//I have tried with and without all the possbilities in the condition below
if (!browser.Browser.Equals("iPad"))
{
    if (isDownload || viewers.Length == 0)
        context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition",
                                      string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", fileName));
    else
        context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + fileName);   
}else
{
    //context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("inline; filename=\"{0}\"", fileName));
}

FileStream iStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
long fileSize = iStream.Length;
long fileLengthToRead = fileSize;
int chunckSize = 10000;
byte[] buffer = new byte[chunckSize];

context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", fileSize.ToString());
context.Response.AppendHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");

try
{
    while (fileLengthToRead > 0 && context.Response.IsClientConnected)
    {
        int read = iStream.Read(buffer, 0, chunckSize);
        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        context.Response.Flush();
        fileLengthToRead = fileLengthToRead - read;
    }
}
catch (HttpException) { }
finally
{
    iStream.Close();
    iStream.Dispose();
}
break;
```

And here is what the headers look like:

```
GET http://sample.com/sample.pdf HTTP/1.1
Host: sample.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-us
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 4_3_4 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8K2 Safari/6533.18.5
Accept: application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
Referer: http://sample.com/sample.aspx

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 218882
Content-Type: application/pdf
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 01 Aug 2012 15:41:06 GMT
```

Comment: Does the iOS device open the PDF if you download from the PDFs URL directly rather than rewrite the file through a handler?  Have you tried different PDF files (not all PDFs are created equal and you may just have a bad PDF. Like HTML browsers, some handle errors better than others.